# Uploaded picture alignment issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

The uploaded picture on my profile is not aligned correctly. When first set, the picture is in the correct position, but after refreshing the page it shifts to the right.  If I use a gravatar it aligns correctly.

This occurs in firefox, chrome and internet explorer.

Here is a link to my profile (this occurs on both meta and the main site)
https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10365/alex

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like
[image: wrongly aligned profile picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

This is fixed in the next build (rev 2014.2.11.1362).